# How to remove item in selected list for kendo ui upload based on its ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

I have multiple kendo upload controls among those I need to clear one of those not all controls. I am trying

```
$(".k-delete").parent().click();
```

but I want clear based on its ID rather than class name. Please can anybody help me

Comment: does `$("#upload").parents(".t-upload").find(".t-upload-files").remove()` help?

Comment: Placed code into code block.

Comment: I tried that, but it was not working for me @Gene R.